# Keymatrix with Raspberry and PCF8574 (c#)

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot, i2c, keypad

Has anyone managed to run a matrix keyboard via i2c? I'm trying to use it via the PCF8574 expansion card.

In my case I use a 4x4 matrix keyboard.
The ShowKeyMatrixEvent event actually fires 3 times, for each row that is not affected: really impractical.
Do you know any alternatives? Even using another expansion chip.

Thank you

```
var settings = new System.Device.I2c.I2cConnectionSettings(1, Convert.ToInt32(_appSettings.KeyPad.i2cAddress, 16));
var i2cDevice = System.Device.I2c.I2cDevice.Create(settings);
var pcf8574 = new Iot.Device.Pcx857x.Pcf8574(i2cDevice);
GpioController gpio = new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Logical, pcf8574);
IEnumerable<int> outputs = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> inputs = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
KeyMatrix keyMatrix = new KeyMatrix(outputs, inputs, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), gpio, true);
keyMatrix.KeyEvent += KeyMatrixEventReceived;
keyMatrix.StartListeningKeyEvent();


void ShowKeyMatrixEvent(KeyMatrix sender, KeyMatrixEvent pinValueChangedEventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff} {pinValueChangedEventArgs.Output}, {pinValueChangedEventArgs.Input}, {pinValueChangedEventArgs.EventType}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

By pressing a key and releasing it I therefore obtain 3 distinct events, one for each excluded row.
For example, by pressing key 1 (and holding it down), I get 3 falling and rising events: one for each excluded row.

If I increase the delay, I risk not intercepting the excluded lines.
In any case, this doesn't have to be the solution: I was hoping there was a way to have the single button pressed, without having to think by exclusion.

```
2023-11-21 19:53:37.3807|0|INFO|ShowKeyMatrixEvent|2023/11/21 19:53:37.380 2, 0, Falling 
2023-11-21 19:53:37.7867|0|INFO|ShowKeyMatrixEvent|2023/11/21 19:53:37.786 3, 0, Falling 
2023-11-21 19:53:38.3961|0|INFO|ShowKeyMatrixEvent|2023/11/21 19:53:38.396 1, 0, Falling 
2023-11-21 19:53:39.6118|0|INFO|ShowKeyMatrixEvent|2023/11/21 19:53:39.611 2, 0, Rising 
2023-11-21 19:53:40.0168|0|INFO|ShowKeyMatrixEvent|2023/11/21 19:53:40.016 3, 0, Rising 
2023-11-21 19:53:40.6245|0|INFO|ShowKeyMatrixEvent|2023/11/21 19:53:40.624 1, 0, Rising
```

Comment: Make sure you power supply is properly grounded , regulated, and has capacitors.  You may be getting bouncing when you push a button causing multiple events to occur.

Comment: Yes, already done.
I also created a Python version and it works perfectly.

Comment: The 10ms delay may be too small.  Following code is using 200ms : https://github.com/MSZ98/pcf8574/blob/main/README.MD

Comment: If python code is working, why are you looking for another expansion chip?  Are the part you are using from Adafruit?  I worked with a Raspberry a couple of years ago.  Brought a Adafruit USB to Serial Cable.  I found many cases on Web saying not to use Chinese substitutes.  The Chinese IC in device had bugs and only small percentage actually worked.  But your python is working.  Are you using same low level drivers with c# and python?  What methods are different between python and c#?  The code inside the event is probably quicker in c# than python which may account for the differences.

Comment: The hardware is the same: in Python it works because it uses a ready-to-use library.
The difference lies in the fact that in Python I essentially have the button pressed, while using the Microsoft libraries for the IOT I have 3 events triggered when the button is released (one for each row, excluding the current one).
I was hoping to find some alternative libraries to Microsoft's ones.

Comment: Read Interrupts here : https://github.com/RobTillaart/PCF8574